# How would i go about looping specific parts of a python function?

Tags: python

So my question is how would I shorten this code and still allow for 3 attempts?

```
def numberguess(answernumber):
  guess=input('guess a number between 1-10: ')
  if guess.isnumeric():
    if guess==answernumber:
      print('Correct')
    else:
      print('Incorrect')
      userguess=input('Two more attempts: ')
      if userguess.isalpha():
        if userguess==answerletter:
          print('Correct')
        else:
          print('Incorrect')
          userguess=input('one more attempt: ')
          if guess.isalpha():
            if userguess==answerletter:
              print('Correct')
            else:
              print('Incorrect, No more attempts remaining')
          else:
            print('Invalid')
      else:
        print('Invalid')
  else:
    print('invalid')
```

I have a set of code that is shorter but I don't know how to go about allowing for multiple tries without it turning into the previous mess of code and I want to know if there's any way to just do a loop like how you would in python(turtle) with the "for i in range:" loop

```
def letterguess(answerletter,userguess):
  answerletter=answerletter.lower()
  userguess=userguess.lower()
  if userguess.isalpha()==False:
    print('Invalid')
    return False
  elif userguess==answerletter:
    print('Correct')
    return True
  elif userguess>answerletter:
    print('guess is too high')
    return False
  else:
    print('guess is too low')
    return False
```

this is the shortened version if you wanted to see the difference, but this one allows for only one try

Answer (score 2):

You've used the word *loop* in your question title, have you tried googling and reading about the types of loop structures available in Python? In your case, you know you want the loop to run three times, so you can use a `for` loop.

So the basic structure is going to look like this:

```py
def number_guess(answer: int, num_attempts: int = 3) -> None:  # The : int and -> None are call type hints or type annotations. I highly highly recommend getting into the habit of using them in Python. It makes your code easier to read and later on, you can use tools like mypy to catch errors before running your code.
    for attempt in range(num_attempts): # Loop a defined number of times
        guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:")
        if validate_guess(guess, answer):  # Wrap up your conditions in a function for readability
            print("Correct")
            break # Exit the loop early because the condition has been met
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    else:  # This part is a weird python thing, it only runs if the loop completes without reaching a break statement. What does it mean if your loop completed without hitting break in this case? It means that the condition never evaluated to true, hence the correct guess wasn't found and the user ran out of tries.
        print("Sorry, you're out of tries")
```

And now you need to define `validate_guess`:

```
def validate_guess(guess: str, answer) -> bool:
    return guess.isnumeric() and int(guess) == answer
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for answering my question, i asked that way cause 1. I'm just a teenager who started learning recently, and 2. i couldn't figure out how to apply for loops into my code, but either way thanks for showing me a way to condense it even tho I'm not sure what some of the stuff you put actually means 

Comment: Which part don't you understand? I recommend that you google anything here that you don't understand and try figure it out as this is all worth knowing early on. If you have more questions on this, feel free to ask here in the comments.

Comment: I added a bunch of extra comments to try clarify it a bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

A compact version might be:

```
def numberguess(answerletter):
    for attempt in range(3):
        user_guess = input('Enter Guess:')
        if user_guess.isnumeric() and int(user_guess)==answerletter:
            print('Correct')
            return True
        else:
            print(f'incorrect, {2-attempt} attempts left')
    print('failed')
    return False
```

What you need to work on:

1. loops. They are used when some operation is needed to be repeated a desired number of times
2. Combining conditions. You dont just list them out in a long if-else ladder. Instead, use logic to determine where and how you can use these conditions more efficiently. Result will be a more efficient and much cleaner code.

Comment: thanks User5 I just didnt know how i was supposed to apply for loops in python to get the effect i wanted, I'm new to python so while i found out how to apply a while loop to my code it was not efficient in the slightest, tho it did modify the original code the least

Answer (score 0):

Ok so uh for some reason I had the odd notion that just because they were used for python(turtle) meant I couldn't use while loops for normal python, here's the revised code using an improvised while loop that doesn't change much of the original code

```
def letterguess(answerletter):
  answerletter=answerletter.lower()
  i=0
  while i<3:
    userguess=input('guess a letter A-Z: ')
    userguess=userguess.lower()
    if userguess.isalpha()==False:
      print('Invalid')
      return False
    elif userguess==answerletter:
      print('Correct')
      i=4
      print('You guessed correctly')
    elif userguess>answerletter:
      print('guess is too high')
      i+=1
    else:
      print('guess is too low')
      i+=1
  else:
    print('you failed to guess')
print(letterguess('L'))
```

And thank you to those who answered my dumb question and just want to make it clear that I started learning python about a month and a half ago so quite frankly I was confused by some of the code you put but thanks for helping me out anyway